# php conditional operator not transient

Tags: php, conditional-operator

I am having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around this, so I thought I will ask it..

I have this code:

```
$x="string";
var_dump($x==0); //says true
var_dump($x==true); //says true
var_dump(true==0); //says false
```

What I understand is:

```
In 1, `string` gets converted to number, which becomes `0` so condition is true
In 2, `string` is a value, so condition is true
In 3, `true` is not equal to `0` so condition is false
```

Individually they all make sense, but in a sequence they just don't! I have heard many people say it is because the conditional operator in PHP is `not transient`. Can someone explain what that means, and how to make sense of this?

Comment: i suppose for 2 that it checks whether the string is empty. For 3, bool equivalent of int 0 is false

Comment: At no point are you actually changing the value of `$x` though, just evaluating it... so it might look weird but it does make sense. `(int) "string" == 0`, `(bool) "string" == true` and `(int) true == 1` ... also `(string) false == ""` and `(string) true == "1"` *shrugs*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why in the world wouldn't that make sense? You never change the value of **x**, so those statements are dependent on the original value of **x** which is "string".

You are assuming **x** is changed to 0 in the first var_dump but it is not. It is merely compared to 0/false. This statement would perform the variable change that you think is happening:

```
var_dump(($x = 0) == 0);
```

Or:

```
var_dump(($x = false) == 0);
```

Comment: So can you explain what being not transient means?

Comment: Well transient means temporary. I'm not sure what is meant by "the conditional operator is NOT transient," but I think you could say "the conditional operator IS transient." Because it doesn't assign a new value to the variable and only temporarily compares it to a different value, you could say it's transient.

Comment: Ah, I see what your question is implying. You mean "transitive" not "transient" and you want to know why true is not equal to 0 when x is equal to both 0 and true. This is because of the data types of the comparison. $x == 0 is comparing it to an integer. Since $x is a string, $x is not numeric and is converted to 0 in the comparison, making it true. In $x == true, it returns true because the string holds a value, and in PHP this means true because you often want to see if the string is set. In true == 0, you're comparing two Boolean values (0 being false) so true does not equal false.

Comment: Transitive being if a = b, b = c, then a = c. i.e. if 1 = true, 2 = true, then 1 = 2, which is false but seems as though it should be true given the PHP logic. The == operator only compares apparent value, not true value. i.e. $x == true returns true because $x is set. It doesn't take into account that $x is a string and true is a Boolean. However, $x === true returns false. Maybe a better example is var_dump(1 == true) and var_dump(1 === true). Clearly, 1 is synonymous with Boolean true, so the first returns true because it doesn't consider the data type. Yet the second returns false because

Comment: 1 is an int and true is a Boolean, making them not equal. a = b, b = c, a = c is transitive because it takes into account the data type by default. In math, it's an integer always. Or decimal, etc. but always a number that you can write on paper that always means the same thing. 1 in a math equation always means 1; it doesn't mean true or anything else. So in PHP this is equal to a === b, b === c, a === c, not a == b, b == c, a == c.